# Extracting only genres from the string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string in following format

```
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name' : 'Drama']
```

etc.
I want to extract the values like Comedy,Drama etc

I have tried to use the following RE with no success.

```
('([^'])*')
```

I am expecting to get the part of string after 'name':   for every string under {} in same list. for Example,`[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]`

My data is coming from a pandas dataframe:

[image: table]

Comment: That looks like almost-JSON-but-not-quite-JSON. Why do you have data in this format? What format is it? Shouldn't you rather parse this format using whatever format parser this is and treat it as native arrays and objects?

Comment: the data i'm trying to parse is an entry in a column in pandas dataframe column.I want to extract only the words like Comedy , Drama etc and replace it with the existing Json-like-String. Also the thing is that Python by default converts the object into string when i try to access it by for loop.

Comment: Is what we're looking at really a *string*, or the output of a Python list-of-dicts…?!

Comment: The Data  is as follows. I just want to extract the information from the data in column.I am not able to figure out how. Here is the link to the image of the data. https://imgur.com/uL1K52m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, use this regex.

```
import re
txt = """
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name' : 'Drama']
"""
results = re.findall("'name'\s*:\s*'([^']+)'", txt)
print(results)
```

Prints:

```
['Comedy', 'Comedy', 'Drama']
```

If you want unique values just do `set(results)`

Comment: The answer you shared was helpful but i wanted all the entries seperately. for example, for    [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]       i would want ['Comedy']      and for [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name' : 'Drama'}] i would want ['Comedy','Drama']     and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @palvarez i will figure out the rest

Comment: @AdityaVartak You could try to extract each list first with the regex `\[.*?\]`